# Chrome extension: how to display tabs horizontally?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'll like to know how I can display Chrome tabs in a horizontal fashion in my side project chrome extension. I saw this functionality in a chrome extension in the Chrome store, but I've had issue on finding a way to build this functionality into my Chrome extension.

I've checked the Chrome API documentation & stackoverflow with no examples found.

The attached image give an illustration of what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks[image]

Comment: There's no API for this so you will have to do it yourself in DOM/CSS/JS.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the information. I am novice to developing with DOM/CSS/JS, Please, will you happen to know any steps I can take in achieving my goal ?